# Jira Ticket best practices

Tags: team-management, user-stories, jira, acceptance-criteria

I've been with two very different companies that both use JIRA Tickets to track work done. The first was corporate company with some high standards when it comes to defining Tickets in Jira, the second a startup that merely writes down a description of needs to be done (Usually a one liner).

Now the second has caused some issues around defining what is expected, information relating about the work, finding out exactly what needs to be done and so forth. I am currently in a position where I can strongly hint or suggest better practices.

My question is - Is there a defined format/standard practice guide when creating Jira tickets to improve workflow?

Comment: Defined standard? Not that I have seen. But one line tickets are an obvious no-no. A principle I work from is that anyone in the delivery team (product owner/developer/tester/ba etc.) should be able to understand the ticket and do the work that they need to do accurately from it. How do you test a one liner that says "fix login process"?

Comment: Hi Cornelis - you've framed and tagged this as a question about Jira, but it sounds like you are asking a question about ticket best practices that is actually tool-agnostic. If you frame and tag it more generally, you might get more responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### User story best practices by Mike Cohn

[Here are some user story best practices by Mike Cohn](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories):

- Write user stories from the perspective of the person who desires the new capability in this format: As a < type of user >, I want < some goal > so that < some reason >.
- Discussions are more important than whatever text is written.
- Add detail by splitting a user story into multiple, smaller user stories.
- Add detail by adding conditions of satisfaction which is simply a high-level acceptance test that will be true after the agile user story is complete.

In addition, in Jira you can link them to related stories.

Comment: Just remember to knot down the discussion during backlog grooming (or add as subtasks). We did not do this earlier and experienced that discussions +1 month back was forgotten when we came to sprint planning and had to do the entire discussion all over again ("what was this issue all about?").